# Populando Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinners

Tenho a seguinte duvida tenho que utilizar alguns Arrays List em meu projeto elas são...

List Restaurante
Pratos Restaurante 1
Pratos Restaurante 2
Preço Restaurante 1
Preço Restaurante 2

Dentro da minha Activity eu coloquei dois Spinners um que vai pegar o Array List Restaurantes e o outro o eu quero que apareça o dados do Array list quando eu selecionar o restaurante e no final eu pegaria e setaria como um Text View do preço.

Segue a imagem para ter uma noção melhor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só para ter uma ideia do que esta sendo populado nos Spinner

```
<string-array name="Restaurantes">
    <item>McDonalds</item>
    <item>KFC</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Restaurante_McDonalds_Pratos">
    <item>Combo Big Mac</item>
    <item>Combo Deluxe Bacon</item>
    <item>Combo Club House</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Restaurante_McDonalds_Pratos_Precos">
    <item>R$ 31,00</item>
    <item>R$ 29,00</item>
    <item>R$ 35,00</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Restaurante_KFC_Pratos">
    <item>Combo Balde de 6 peças</item>
    <item>Combo Balde de 9 peças</item>
    <item>Combo Balde de 12 peças</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Restaurante_KFC_Pratos_Precos">
    <item>R$ 25,00</item>
    <item>R$ 35,00</item>
    <item>R$ 45,00</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tá populando de acordo com o spinner pratos de acordo com a seleção do spinner de restaurantes através do setOnItemSelectedListener.

```
spnRestaurante.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selected = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            restaurante.setRestaurante(selected);

            if(selected.equals("McDonalds")){
               //seta o adapter dos pratos para o spinner dos pratos
             } if(selected.equals("KFC")){
               //seta o adapter dos pratos para o spinner dos pratos
             }
        }
```